# bundle or rails runner has any kind of cache for gem source files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm receiving an error from a gem file:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/psd-2.1.2/lib/psd/layer_info/typetool.rb:127:in `to_css': (error is not important)
```

I want to debug the gem, so I went to that file and added a `debugger`. It doesn't works. Next I added a `raise`, just to test. Doesn't works. I went to lunch, and 20 minutes after the `debugger` line was working. I removed it, run the process again and the debugger was still pausing the script execution, even when the line was not longer on the file.

I run my script with

```
rails runner myscript.rb
```

Why is this happening? Is there some kind of cache/opcode that avoids to read the gems source file? I'm not running a webserver, and there is no instance of the application running.

Comment: I know is not good to modify code on gems. I just want to do on this gem for a very specific issue, and yes, I know i could fork and install the gem from my own repository but I got very interested with this behaviour and wants to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things might help you.

1. How are you opening the code? `bundle open`? Or are just manually opening the files in the `rvm` directories? Using `bundle open <gem name>` will be easiest.
2. Is spring running? When you modify the gems in your bundle, you will need to issue the command `spring stop` from the root of your code. This will allow the changes to actually be used.

I bet that `spring` is causing your issues. If it is, you will need to run `spring stop` each time that it automatically starts and you'd like to change the code.